# SwipeRefreshLayout is not stopping refreshing

Tags: android

Inside `onCreateView` method of a fragment:

```
swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            refresh();
        }
});
```

My `refresh()` method is like:

```
public void {
    //some action

    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
}
```

But sometimes `swipeRefresLayout` is not stopping refreshing. When I debug the code, it isn't even going to `refresh()` method.

How can I fix it?

**Edited:**
More clear code here:

```
public class VisaCardsFragment extends Fragment {

@Bind(R.id.swipe_refresh_layout)
SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;

@Bind(R.id.recycler_view_visa_cards)
RecyclerView recyclerViewVisaCards;

@Bind(R.id.text_view_message)
TextView textViewMessage;

private List<Card> cards;
private List<VisaCard> visaCards;
private VisaCardsAdapter adapter;


public VisaCardsFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_visa_cards, container, false);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

    visaCards = new ArrayList<>();
    adapter = new VisaCardsAdapter(visaCards);
    recyclerViewVisaCards.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerViewVisaCards.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);
    recyclerViewVisaCards.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(VisaCardsFragment.this.getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));


    cards = Card.getActiveCards();
    if (cards.isEmpty()) {
        showMessage("Cards unavailable");
        return view;
    }

    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
    getVisaResponse(); // method containing server request (RESTful) to get visa cards (VisaCard) using the data of cards (Card)


    swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            refresh();
        }
    });

    return view;
}

public void refresh() {
    hideMessage();
    cards = Card.getActiveCards();
    if (cards.isEmpty()) {
        clearList();
        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        showMessage("Visa cards not found");
        return;
    }
    getVisaResponse();// method containing server request (RESTful) to get visa cards (VisaCard) using the data of cards (Card)
}

public void showMessage(String message) {
    textViewMessage.setText(message);
    textViewMessage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

public void hideMessage() {
    textViewMessage.setText("");
    textViewMessage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

}

Comment: share your whole code

Comment: Nilesh Rathod, I have added code, can you take a look?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I want to answer my own question so that someone will find the solution, if he/she makes the same mistake.

My problem was that **sometimes `swipeRefresLayout` is not stopping refreshing. When I debug the code, it isn't even going to `refresh()` method.** As you can see it was not always.

Okay, when did it happen? It happened whet `cards` list was empty.

```
...

cards = Card.getActiveCards();
if (cards.isEmpty()) {
    showMessage("Cards unavailable");
    return view;
}

//some code here

swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        refresh();
    }
});

...
```

As it was written when `cards` list is empty, it returns `view` containing `swipeRefreshLayout` without `refreshListener`. Hence, when you refresh, nothing happens since there's not a `listener`.

The solution is just to setting `listener` before returning the `view`, like this:

```
...

swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        refresh();
    }
});

//some code here

cards = Card.getActiveCards();
if (cards.isEmpty()) {
    showMessage("Cards unavailable");
    return view;
}
...
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listaNoticias"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" >
    <ListView>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Here is the java code of the implementation;

```
     public class classname extends Fragment implements OnRefreshListener {
    SwipeRefreshLayout swipeLayout;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.classname, container, false);

    swipeLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.swipe_container);
    swipeLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);


@Override
public void onRefresh() {
   //action
   //and set false to stop.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener` will only be triggered when the swipe gesture is detected, see the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener.html#onRefresh()):

> Called when a swipe gesture triggers a refresh.

but in your code, you start your refresh by calling:

```
swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
```

So the refresh indicator just start refreshing from here, and the `SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener` won't be triggered. If you want to start refreshing when your `Fragment` start, just call `refresh()` right after `setRefreshing(true)`:

```
swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
refresh();
```

Or if you want to refresh until the user make a swipe gesture, just remove this line.

```
swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
```

and your `SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener` will be triggered when the swipe gesture is detected.

Comment: The reason why I called `swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);` is that when fragment is added to the activity for the first time, the request should be sent to the server. Then I set refresh listener so that  when a user swipes to refresh, another request is sent to the server in the background.

Comment: So just call `refresh();` manually for the first time. just after `swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);`.

Comment: If you don't call `refresh()`, then the swipeRefreshLayout is stay at a refreshing state, and no swipe gesture will be detected, then it cannot stop refreshing.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the time to run swipeRefreshLayout using the method I used as follows:

```
        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    loadPosts(); //This is where I want to update my data
                    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                }
            }, 1000); // This is how you can choose when it will end

        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue of not stopping refreshing, In my case, I forgot the set listener. Like below

```
        viewBinding.swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this)
```

so, take a look at this also, if someone facing the same issue.